# How to validate the enum values for python dataclass attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `dataclass` and `enum` values which are as below:

```
@dataclass
class my_class:
id: str
dataType: CheckTheseDataTypes

class CheckTheseDataTypes(str,Enum):
FIRST="int"
SECOND="float"
THIRD = "string"
```

I want to check whenever this `dataclass` is called it should have the `datatype` values only from the given `enum` list. I wrote an external validator initially like the below:

```
if datatype not in CheckTheseDataTypes.__members__:
```

I am actually looking for something where I don't need this external validation. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **post_init**() method to do that.

```
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass


class CheckTheseDataTypes(str, Enum):
    FIRST = "int"
    SECOND = "float"
    THIRD = "string"


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    id: str
    data_type: CheckTheseDataTypes

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.data_type not in list(CheckTheseDataTypes):
            raise ValueError('data_type id not a valid value')


data = MyClass(id='abc', data_type="wrong_type")
```

A couple of side notes:

- By convention class should use the CamelCase naming style
- The order of things matters. Python reads code top to bottom,
  so by having the Enum under the @dataclass you will get a `NameError: name 'CheckTheseDataTypes' is not defined`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, your second point makes sense. That's why we created a different class.